# Lerping while an animation is playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

So here I am trying to do like peaking or leaning in my game

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
{
                curAngle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(curAngle, maxAngle, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

and I am like lerping the spine to the curangle **I tried doing it with lerp but got the same results** and the animations are like blocking them cause there is always an animation playing and the spine cannot go out the animation range **I didn't find a leaning animation sharing a link of an animation would be helpful too**

Comment: `animations are like blocking them cause there is always an animation playing` what exactly do you mean? Have in mind that usually if you speak about "animation" you refer to the `Animator`, `Animation` or `Timelime`. So are you using any of these? If so then yes indeed: The Animator is one of the very last things running within a frame and will overrule whatever you do in code as soon as any of the animation clips holds a key frame on your field/property! From your usage you are currently only updating a field and we would need more context how you use that exactly

Comment: I'd advise against doing this in code - create an animation instead, far easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the animation is blocking your changes. Directly manipulating the transform of something that is animating will result in the animation overriding the transform change.

The best way to create this functionality, assuming you're using the Animator, create a lean animation for both sides, and hook this up as an animation layer with a mask for just the bones required for the lean to work. Your code will then just lerp the player's input to -1, 0, 1 as an Animator variable. The layering is needed so your base animation still plays.

A hacky way to solve this is to simply disable animations while leaning. Of course, you'll need to re-enable them after the lean. However, this isn't really solving the issue, so you'll still need to implement it as above properly in the future if you ever intend animations to run at the same time as direct transform manipulation